# Export data only from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, export, mysql-workbench, workbench

How can I export from MySQL Workbench only the datas of my tables? I not found this option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From menu select `Server->Data export`, then choos your schema from left pane and then tables from right pane. From drop down menu select `Dump Data Only`. Click on `Start Export` button to export your data.

Comment: ... or use the table data export to csv/json, via the context menu of a table.